# Resource ID from subdomain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

My urls are:

```
http://website.com/academies/1

http://website.com/academies/1/courses

http://website.com/academies/1/courses/1

http://website.com/academies/1/courses/1/lessons

http://website.com/academies/1/courses/1/lessons/1
```

But I want to use it subdomain for each academies

```
http://1.website.com/
http://1.website.com/courses/
http://1.website.com/courses/1
http://1.website.com/courses/1/lessons
http://1.website.com/courses/1/lessons/1
```

**I want to do this, but it shouldn't be mandatory. Both urls'schema should be valid at the same time**

Routes.rb

```
resources :academies do

    resources :users
    resources :courses
    resources :posts
```